# Whois command corrupted on mac

Tags: macos, dns, osx-mavericks, whois

Whois lookup is not displaying correct information. Dig and other network commands work perfectly correct and I'm able to connect to any/everything. However, this whois lookup corruption concerns me. Any ideas? Thanks! The reason I ask is because this is needed for a networking class (professor showed whois in conjunction with showing how to program firewall rules, and I need to be able to do that for the final). It works 'normally' (that is, lists domain info) on other's computers, and if I connect via telnet to internic, I can get it, but the whois command on my mac won't. Any ideas?

Example:

> whois google.com
>
> Whois Server Version 2.0 Domain names in the .com and
>   .net domains can now be registered with many different competing
>   registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net for detailed information.
>
> GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.HAVENDATA.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZOMBIED.AND.HACKED.BY.WWW.WEB-HACK.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZNAET.PRODOMEN.COM GOOGLE.COM.YUCEKIRBAC.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.WORDT.DOOR.VEEL.WHTERS.GEBRUIKT.SERVERTJE.NET GOOGLE.COM.VN
>   GOOGLE.COM.VABDAYOFF.COM GOOGLE.COM.UY GOOGLE.COM.UA GOOGLE.COM.TW
>   GOOGLE.COM.TR GOOGLE.COM..FIND.CRACKZ.WITH.SEARCH.GULLI.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.SPROSIUYANDEKSA.RU
>   GOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.SOUTHBEACHNEEDLEARTISTRY.COM GOOGLE.COM.SHQIPERIA.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.SA GOOGLE.COM.PK GOOGLE.COM.PE
>   GOOGLE.COM.NS2.CHALESHGAR.COM GOOGLE.COM.NS1.CHALESHGAR.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.MY GOOGLE.COM.MX GOOGLE.COM.LOLOLOLOLOL.SHTHEAD.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.LASERPIPE.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
>   GOOGLE.COM.IS.HOSTED.ON.PROFITHOSTING.NET
>   GOOGLE.COM.IS.APPROVED.BY.NUMEA.COM GOOGLE.COM.HK
>   GOOGLE.COM.HAS.LESS.FREE.***.IN.ITS.SEARCH.ENGINE.THAN.SECZY.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES GOOGLE.COM.FIBERTREAT.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.DO GOOGLE.COM.CO GOOGLE.COM.CN GOOGLE.COM.BR
>   GOOGLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM GOOGLE.COM.AU GOOGLE.COM.ARTVISUALRIO.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.AR GOOGLE.COM.AFRICANBATS.ORG GOOGLE.COM To single out one
>   record, look it up with "xxx", where xxx is one of the of the records
>   displayed above. If the records are the same, look them up with "=xxx"
>   to receive a full display for each record.
>
> Last update of whois database: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 21:21:54 UTC <<<
>   NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
>   registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the
>   registry is currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily
>   reflect the expiration date of the domain name registrant's agreement
>   with the sponsoring registrar. Users may consult the sponsoring
>   registrar's Whois database to view the registrar's reported date of
>   expiration for this registration. TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized
>   to access or query our Whois database through the use of electronic
>   processes that are high-volume and automated except as reasonably
>   necessary to register domain names or modify existing registrations;
>   the Data in VeriSign Global Registry Services' ("VeriSign") Whois
>   database is provided by VeriSign for information purposes only, and to
>   assist persons in obtaining information about or related to a domain
>   name registration record. VeriSign does not guarantee its accuracy. By
>   submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide by the following terms of
>   use: You agree that you may use this Data only for lawful purposes and
>   that under no circumstances will you use this Data to: (1) allow,
>   enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass unsolicited,
>   commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone, or
>   facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
>   that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
>   repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
>   prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree
>   not to use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to
>   access or query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to
>   register domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign
>   reserves the right to restrict your access to the Whois database in
>   its sole discretion to ensure operational stability. VeriSign may
>   restrict or terminate your access to the Whois database for failure to
>   abide by these terms of use. VeriSign reserves the right to modify
>   these terms at any time. The Registry database contains ONLY .COM,
>   .NET, .EDU domains and Registrars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The whois command on your Mac is perfectly fine.

You're simply querying a different NICNAME server with each tool.  The BSD `whois` tool in MacOS 10 uses the `whois-servers.net.` mechanism, and in this case is querying the `com.whois-servers.net.` NICNAME server, run by Verisign Incorporated.  Other people's computers are using a different `whois` command that probably hardwires `whois.networksolutions.com.`, run by Network Solutions LLC, as the NICNAME server.

What you see is what the different NICNAME servers are actually publishing.  This is nothing to do with your client tool at all.  People have actually registered all of those.  Note what the MacOS manual says about the Network Solutions NICNAME server.  You're querying *the registry*'s NICNAME server, and seeing a whole load of registrations made through several different registrars, from MarkMonitor to Tucows.  The other people are querying *one registrar's* NICNAME server, and seeing only the registrations made through that specific registrar.

Run

```
whois '=google.com'
```

with the BSD `whois` tool and you'll receive extended output from the registry's NICNAME server showing where each registrar's individual NICNAME server is.  (The output in your question tells you this very trick.)  Again, this is a server-side function, and not all NICNAME servers work the same way — as you can see if you try the same trick with the Network Solutions LLC NICNAME server.

One of the reasons that `whois` commands vary is that the days of there being one place, or even a few places, to go for NICNAME service are long past.  You're using one of the more modern `whois` tools that uses one of two available DNS mechanisms to automatically locate the NICNAME server to use for any given domain name.  Other, clunkier and higher-maintenance, `whois` tools have hardwired NICNAME server names, or configuration files that need regular servicing.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2010). [`whois`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/iu/commands/whois.html).  *Internet Utilities for OS/2 user guide*.
- [`whois`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/whois.1.html).  2004-06-14.  MacOS 10 Manual Pages. Apple corporation.
- Marco d'Itri. [`whois`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whois.1.html).  Ubuntu manual pages.  Canonical.
- ["Site Configuration"](https://www.gnu.org/software/jwhois/manual/html_node/Site-Configuration.html#Site-Configuration).  GNU `jwhois` manual.  Free Software Foundation.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2009). ["NICNAME clients that use SRV lookups"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-srv-record-use-by-clients.html#NICNAME).  *Some application clients use SRV lookups, a few (to their embarrassment) do not.*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2009). [*Providing your own NICNAME service.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/diy-nicname-service.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: So how can I construct the command so that I get the domain info specifically (and only) for google.com, etc? I know that on Ubuntu/Debian Linux (I realize those are different. My friend installed Ubuntu, then put Debian on top for layout) and OS X Snow Leopard's whois commands will give the domain info only for google.com, etc. I can use online who.is to get the info, but now it's a question understanding the command itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually more simple than @JdeBP explained. I built and maintain my own whois lookup service/tool at http://gwhois.org/ and I have come to learn the ins and outs of different domain name registries.

The issue is that the `whois` command on your Mac is not sending the query to the .COM whois server in the correct format.

To fix this, you need to use the following command:

```
whois -h whois.verisign-grs.com "domain google.com"
```

### Explanation:

The whois server for the .COM tld is `whois.verisign-grs.com`, managed by Verisign (the .COM registry).

If you connect via TCP to `whois.verisign-grs.com:43` and send `?` you get some information on how queries are supposed to be sent to this whois server:

```
To search for a specific record TYPE:
-------------------------------------
domain
nameserver
registrar

Other WHOIS keywords:

EXPand                   Show all parts of display without asking.
FUll or '='              Show detailed display for EACH match.
SUMmary                  Always show summary, even for only one match.
HELP                     Enters help program for full documentation.
PArtial or trailing '.'  Match targets STARTING with given string.
Q, QUIT, or hit RETURN   Exits WHOIS.
```

So, the output that you receive on your Mac is what you get when you only send `google.com` to `whois.verisign-grs.com:43`. It tries to show you all matching results!

All those `google.com` entries are actually name servers (for DNS) that have been registered by domain name owners.

For example, in your question, you can see `GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM` listed. Here's what you get if you send `nameserver GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM` to the .COM whois server:

```
Server Name: GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM
IP Address: 88.246.115.134
Registrar: PDR LTD. D/B/A PUBLICDOMAINREGISTRY.COM
Whois Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
Referral URL: http://www.PublicDomainRegistry.com
```

And if you only wanted to get the registration info for `google.com`, you need to send `domain google.com` to get this response:

```
Domain Name: GOOGLE.COM
Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Referral URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Status: serverDeleteProhibited
Status: serverTransferProhibited
Status: serverUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 20-jul-2011
Creation Date: 15-sep-1997
Expiration Date: 14-sep-2020
```

---

Source: http://blog.gwhois.org/insight/not-all-whois-servers-are-created-equal/

Answer (score 0):

iglvzx's answer is informative but only returns the THIN whois. What people usually want is both the THIN and THICK whois. The THICK whois contains registrant information.

First query the THIN whois to find the THICK whois server as in iglvzx's answer:

`whois -h whois.verisign-grs.com "domain google.com"`

Then grab the THICK whois server from the `Whois Server` line:

`Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com`

Now query the THICK whois server:

`whois -h whois.markmonitor.com google.com`

`Domain Name: google.com
Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited)
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited)
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Dns Admin
Registrant Organization: Google Inc.
Registrant Street: Please contact contact-admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Registrant City: Mountain View
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Postal Code: 94043
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.6502530000
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +1.6506188571
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: dns-admin@google.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: DNS Admin
Admin Organization: Google Inc.
Admin Street: 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
Admin City: Mountain View
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Postal Code: 94043
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.6506234000
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax: +1.6506188571
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: dns-admin@google.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: DNS Admin
Tech Organization: Google Inc.
Tech Street: 2400 E. Bayshore Pkwy
Tech City: Mountain View
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Postal Code: 94043
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.6503300100
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax: +1.6506181499
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: dns-admin@google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com`