# What this strange output in Network Utility means when I do whois for apple.com?

Tags: networking, macos, whois

I did a `whois` command for `apple.com` in Network Utility and got output which incluces this text:

```
APPLE.COM-INTERNATIONALSECURE.COM
APPLE.COM.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES
APPLE.COM.IS.0WN3D.BY.GULLI.COM
APPLE.COM.IS.OWN3D.BY.NAKEDJER.COM
APPLE.COM.MORE.INFO.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.WAS.PWNED.BY.M1CROSOFT.COM
APPLE.COM.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
APPLE.COM.WWW.ZON.COM
APPLE.COM.ZON.COM
APPLE.COM
```

I got this output both when I was at home and at work. What this could mean? When I do `whois` for `apple.com` on thirdparty services in browswer, I do not get this output. Is something wrong with my system? (10.12.2, MBP Late 2013.)

Comment: Igor, please, take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/734391/238539). It is about the same problem as you have and it explains why it happens.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://superuser.com/q/37954/238539) explains a lot.

Comment: I see that my question is clearly a duplicate. I'll search better next time.

Answer (score 4):

Neither apple.com is hacked nor there is something wrong with your system. Somebody is just being clever by registering a domain with apple.com in it. You can check [this](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r17341459-Microsoft-WHOIS-hacked) for more details but the idea is same.

Comment: Thanks for answer. No need to poke fun or whatever about what I am using. I love my Mac and if you don't — feel free to use what you like.

Comment: it was just a joke. please don't take it so hard.